# Undefined 'callback' with Async Waterfall / Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js, waterfall

I am trying to get a waterfall working in Node.js using Async but I keep getting the error

> callback (null, articleDataSafe, req);
>                                                                   ^
>   TypeError: undefined is not a function

The code is as follows

```
async.waterfall([
                        function sanitizeData (articleData, req, callback) {

                                articleDataSafe = sanitizeArticle(articleData);
                                console.log('s1');
                                callback (null, articleDataSafe, req);

                        },

                        function _validateData (articleDataSafe, req, callback) {

                               var errors = validateArticle(articleData);
                               var err = null;
                               if(errors.length > 0){
                                    // return error messages back to the browser
                                    err = JSON.stringify({'error': errors, "message": "fail"});
                                 };
                                console.log('s2');

                               callback (err, articleDataSafe, req);

                        },

                        function _saveArticle (articleDataSafe, req, callback) {

                                // work out the tags hash
                                var tags = articleDataSafe['tags'];
                                var tagsArray = tags.split(",");
                                tagsArray.sort();
                                var tagsString = tagsArray.join(); 
                                var hashedTags = sha512(tagsString);
                                articleDataSafe['hashedTags'] = hashedTags;

                                // then save the articles
                                var savedArticle = saveArticle(req, articleDataSafe);

                                console.log('s3');

                                if(!savedArticle){
                                    var err = JSON.stringify({'error': 'notSaveArticle', 'message': 'fail'});
                                }

                                callback (err, articleDataSafe);

                        },

                        function _saveTags (articleDataSafe, callback) {

                                var tagsDone = saveTags(articleDataSafe);

                                if(tagsDone.length > 0){
                                    // return error messages back to the browser
                                    var err = JSON.stringify({'error': tagsDone, "message": "fail"});
                                 };
                                console.log('s4');

                                callback (err, articleDataSafe);

                        },

                        function _saveTagSets (articleDataSafe, callback) {

                                var tagSetsDone = saveTagSets(data);

                                if(tagSetsDone.length > 0){
                                    // return error messages back to the browser
                                    var err = JSON.stringify({'error': errors, "message": "fail"});
                                 };
                                console.log('s5');

                                callback (err, articleDataSafe);

                        }
                    ], function (error, success) {

                        var responseMessage = {'error': '', "message": "success"};

                        if (error) { 
                            responseMessage = error; 
                        } 

                        res.end(JSON.stringify(responseMessage));

                    });
```

Can any explain what is going wrong. I have been trying for ages now to get it working with no luck.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Cs1h

Comment: Wait, why are you using `async.waterfall` at all when you have nothing asynchronous to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The first function is passed no other argument than the callback](https://github.com/caolan/async/#waterfalltasks-callback). You'd need to start like this:

```
async.waterfall([
    function sanitizeData (callback) {
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^ no articleData, no req
        articleDataSafe = sanitizeArticle(articleData);
        console.log('s1');
        callback (null, articleDataSafe, req);
    },
    …
```

However I doubt you need async at all.

Comment: Thanks Bergi, that seems to work. I will need async later on for more complex matters but I wanted to use with something more simple first.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi . This solved a bugging careless mistake i was sitting on